# Will GParted automatically format to ext3 when repartioning?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, ntfs, ext3

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 on a 500Gb hard drive. Here is what Ubuntu's Hard Disk analyser is showing me:

[image: Hard Disk Analyser image]

I want to release the bulk of Partition 3 (327Gb) which is currently allocated to Windows 7 for Ubuntu.  I can shrink that partition using Windows 7 itself and then use GParted to create a new partition there which can be used by Ubuntu.  However Partition 3 is currently formatted to NTFS.

So my question is when I create that new partition will GParted automatically reformat to ext3?  If not can it remain NTFS and still be used by Ubuntu?

All help gratefully received with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No!

When you create a new partition using GParted, it gives you an option to format to your choice of FSType. If you dont format, the partition become unusable.

TO install Ubuntu you need ext[n] type partition at least for system directories like `/`,`/boot`, `/var`. I am not sure if you can have `/home` on NTFS or FAT partition. If you are unsure or dont want separate partitions, then its better to create a single ext4 partition for `/`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I ended up with a 'demountable' drive which was EVEN BETTER than what I had expected.  But now I have enough space to move most of my non regular stuff from the /home partition.